# Windows taskbar - change text displayed for minimized windows?

Tags: windows-explorer, taskbar

Working in Windows 10. I often have a number of minimized windows of Windows Explorer, opened to various network folders.

On the taskbar, the minimized windows show with the familiar yellow Windows Explorer icon, followed by the address of the folder. In my case though, all of the locations start with (for example):
\\phtmsil00.tisln01

and as a result, if I have 4 Windows Explorer windows minimized, on the taskbar, they all appear identical, i.e. as:
\\phtmsil00.tisln01...     \\phtmsil00.tisln01...   \\phtmsil00.tisln01...  \\phtmsil00.tisln01...

I wanted to know if there was a way to configure the taskbar so that instead of showing the left-most 20ish characters of the folder location (again, since this means they all appear identical), it shows the right-most 20ish characters. That would allow me to see on the taskbar which folder goes with which minimized window.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task bar only uses the window's Title, so we have to change a setting in Explorer:

1. Open: File Explorer > View > Options > Change folder and search options > View tab
2. Uncheck "Display the full path in the title bar", and click OK

Now you should see only the current folder name in the task bar for each explorer window instead of the full path.

---

Another option is to "shorten" the names. One way to do this is by mapping common folders as a network drive. For example, you can map

`\\long-server-name.domain.com\shared\folder\name\` to `X:`

Then only see `X:\subfolder` as the full path

Comment: Thank you! I had forgot all about the "Display the full path in the title bar" option. Much better now, and I can try the mapping thing if I need to display more than just the folder name.